# OpenPyXL - Identify range of cells styled Centered Across Selection

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am parsing spreadsheets via OpenPyXL and I wish to know if one or more ***non-merged*** cells is configured to be centered across selection, and to get the extents of that selection.

This is quite straight-forward with merged cells (using `worksheet.merged_cells` ranges), but *is there any way to similarly identify the extents of a horizontal group of* ***non-merged cells*** *where text is centered across the group of cells?*

Comment: This question was originally posted as #56173906

Comment: Correct - and it was answered by referring me to the docs for merged cells, which did not answer my question. I left a comment requesting clarification, but it was not answered. So after a few days, I rephrased, clarified and reposted the question to make clear what I was asking. From your response, and since you are the author of OpenPyXL (for which I am eternally grateful) I will assume the answer is ***you can't get there from here.***

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way in OpenPyXL to identify the extents of a horizontal group of non-merged cells where text is centered across the group of cells.

As you pointed out, it is possible to get this information for ***merged*** cells (using the `worksheet.merged_cells` ranges), but no way to do so for non-merged cells.

I believe that Charlie's answer to [your earlier (deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173906/openpyxl-report-if-a-cell-is-styled-to-center-across-selection-and-return-extent) attempted to say that, but I agree that the response could have been more clear.